# No encuentro el fallo (Java)

Tags: java, array, condiciones

estoy desarrollando un programita sencillo que identifique la documentación y te diga qué tipo es. Lo hago recorriendo dos arrays y haciendo las comprobaciones con unos if, pero haga lo que haga el último if machaca el valor de los demás, paso el código:

```
            // creo dos arrays donde pongo los valores permitidos
            char[] fisica = { '0', '1', '2', '3', '4', '5', '6', '7', '8',
                    '9', 'K', 'L', 'M', 'X', 'Y', 'Z' };
            char[] juridica = { 'A', 'B', 'C', 'D', 'E', 'F', 'G', 'H',
                    'J', 'N', 'P', 'Q', 'R', 'S', 'U', 'V', 'W' };
            // recorro los arrays para saber que tipo de persona es
            for (i = 0; i < fisica.length; i++) {
                if (fisica[i] == documentacion.charAt(0)) {
                    descripcion = "Españoles con DNI";
                }
                //.....aqui van mas if
                if (fisica[i] == documentacion.charAt(0)) {
                    descripcion = "Letra reservada para cuando se agoten los 'Y' para Extranjeros identificados por la Policía con un NIE";
                }
            }
            for (i = 0; i < juridica.length; i++) {
                if (juridica[i] == documentacion.charAt(0)) {
                    descripcion = "Sociedades anónimas";
                }
                //....aqui van mas if
                if (juridica[i] == documentacion.charAt(0)) {
                    descripcion = "Establecimientos permanentes de entidades no residentes en España";
                }
            }
```

Me reconoce si es persona física o jurídica, pero sólo guarda los últimos valores asignados en el if de cada bucle.
Gracias de antemano.

Comment: No estas concatenando las descripciones si es eso a lo que te refieres. Si quieres que se concatenen tendras que poner `descripcion += "string"` o `descripcion = descripcion + "string"`

Comment: No, compruebo el primer caracter de documentación ( que es el dni o nif ) y según la letra o número que sea pues se le asigna una descripción.

Comment: ¿La descripción no tendría que variar en función de el valor de i? La comprobación para entrar en el if es siempre la misma, si la cumple el último if siempre va a ser el que determine el resultado porque va a sobreescribir los anteriores.

Answer (score 4):

No tengo claro qué intentas, pero tienes dos if dentro de cada bucle con la misma condición, con lo que se ejecutan las sentencias de los dos:

```
if (juridica[i] == documentacion.charAt(0)) {
    descripcion = "Sociedades anónimas";
}
// ...aqui van mas if
if (juridica[i] == documentacion.charAt(0)) {
    descripcion = "Establecimientos permanentes de entidades no residentes en España";
}
```

Por tanto `descripción`, siempre que `juridica[i] == documentacion.charAt(0)`, tendrá el valor `"Establecimientos permanentes ..."` porque es la última asignación que se hace, cancelando la primera.

Answer (score 0):

puedes modificar el codigo para que sea mas eficiente de esta manera:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
     // creo dos arrays donde pongo los valores permitidos
    String[] fisica = { "0", "1", "2", "3", "4", "5", "6", "7", "8",
            "9", "K", "L", "M", "X", "Y", "Z" };
    String[] juridica = { "A", "B", "C", "D", "E", "F", "G", "H",
            "J", "N", "P", "Q", "R", "S", "U", "V", "W" };

    List<String> lFisica = new ArrayList<String>(Arrays.asList(fisica)); 
    List<String> lJuridica = new ArrayList<String>(Arrays.asList(juridica));

    char documentacion='B';
    String descripcion="";

    String ldoc = String.valueOf(documentacion);

    if (lFisica.contains(ldoc)) {
        descripcion = "Españoles con DNI";
    } else {
        if ((lJuridica.contains(ldoc))) {
            descripcion = "Letra reservada para cuando se agoten los 'Y' para Extranjeros identificados por la Policía con un NIE";             
        } else {
            descripcion="No Ubicado";
        }
    }
}
```

Modifica el programa para solucionar el problema indicado por el amigo https://es.stackoverflow.com/users/22851/pablo-lozano , parece un problema de logica tal como el indica.

Saludos